# Methods to make a backup of the sytem boot disk, UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

I have a system disk that is on my system on a 2TB drive that is a VD as part of a RAID. The other 5 drives are setup as a RAID5.  See the screenshot below.  The system is probably never going to get much larger that 300 GB or so.  I think it is possible to resize that Ext4 partition using Gparted or Disks.  I have not tried that yet because I want to make sure that all is backed up well, even though I have a system on an SSD as well.

Anyways, if I try to make a disk image of the whole disk, I can do that, but with a 2TB disk using the Disks application that is bundled with UBUNTU that might take the better part of a day, but if I could resize the system partition and then just image the boot partitions and the partition that actually has the system on it it would not be too large, and I might be able to restore it to a smaller disk.  Is there a way to do that ?  Instead of making an image of the entire disk, can you create an image of just the Ext4 partition that has the system on it and then restore it to just about any other disk ?  If so, how do you deal with the boot partitions (the first 2).

Just looking for a good way and somewhat fast way to make a backup of my system disk.

I did get "Clonezilla", so I will take a look at that.

[image: Disks App]

Comment: You need to use some ackup software. There;s plenty of choices that only back up the actual used data, not just store a multiple terabyte disk image. Your question as posed is unfortunately too vague; you need to research backup software.